# How to use the $scope out restangular function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angularjs, fullcalendar, restangular

```
Restangular.all('events').getList().then(function(event) {
    $scope.events = event;
});

$scope.calConfig = {
        views: [
             {"type": "agenda", "label": "Agenda"}, 
             {"type": "agendaDay", "label": "Day"}, 
             {"type": "agendaWeek", "label": "Week"}, 
             {"type": "month", "label": "Month"},
        ],
        view: "agendaWeek",
        eventSources: [$scope.events],
        now: moment().toDate(),

            /*/Callback Methods */
        },
```

I'm trying  to use restangular to get data from my MongoDB, then use the data for the fullcalendar. The issue is the $scope.events is undefined when it is using out of the restangular block.

How can I use it for the $scope.calConfig?

Answer (score 1):

This line of code `$scope.calConfig = { ... }` runs before the Restangular call does.

You need to set the config once the Restangular call completes.

```
Restangular.all('events').getList().then(function(event) {
    $scope.events = event;

    $scope.calConfig = {
        views: [
             {"type": "agenda", "label": "Agenda"}, 
             {"type": "agendaDay", "label": "Day"}, 
             {"type": "agendaWeek", "label": "Week"}, 
             {"type": "month", "label": "Month"},
        ],
        view: "agendaWeek",
        eventSources: [$scope.events],
        now: moment().toDate(),

            /*/Callback Methods */
    };
});
```

This is because the Restangular code is asynchronous. You're basically asking it to execute something and `then` call a function once it's completed.

For more information on this, look at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q

---

**Update:** This moves your config code into it's own function and calls it once the request returns a positive response. You should probably handle a negative response.

```
Restangular.all('events').getList().then(function(event) {
    $scope.events = event;
    $scope.config();
});

$scope.config = function() {
    $scope.calConfig = {
        views: [
             {"type": "agenda", "label": "Agenda"}, 
             {"type": "agendaDay", "label": "Day"}, 
             {"type": "agendaWeek", "label": "Week"}, 
             {"type": "month", "label": "Month"},
        ],
        view: "agendaWeek",
        eventSources: [$scope.events],
        now: moment().toDate()
    };
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, But apparently I don't want to put the $scope.calConfig into then(), because the $scope.calConfig is huge block which I didn't post all of them. So Do we have any other ways to do that?

Comment: @user1070111 you do, you can call a method on the callback. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The restangular call is async; you would need to either put the `$scope.calConfig` into the callback, or update the config when the callback is executed.